# Inject an array of Objects in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I would like to achieve something similar to the following in Guice:

```
public MyClass {

    private final InjectedObject[] injectedObjects;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(InjectedObject[] injectedObjects) {
        this.injectedObjects=injectedObjects;
    }
}
```

ie I would like to be able to create a certain number of instances of an object, and inject them into another object as an array. I could probably do this instead:

```
public MyClass {

    private final InjectedObject[] injectedObjects;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(InjectedObjectProvider injectedObjectProvider) {
        this.injectedObjects=injectedObjectProvider.getArrayOfInjectedObjects(5);
    }
}
```

...but I was wondering if there was another route that was more elegant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm curious why you want several objects created eagerly. You might have success injecting a `Provider<InjectedObject>`, and calling `Provider.get()` each time you need an instance. If you really need 5, you could build 'em in a loop:

```
public MyClass {
  private final List<InjectedObject> injectedObjects;

  @Inject
  public MyClass(Provider<InjectedObject> injectedObjectProvider) {
    injectedObjects = new ArrayList<InjectedObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      injectedObjects.add(injectedObjectProvider.get());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the reason for having several provided eagerly is to be able to place them into a ThreadPool - the number of instances in the pool will depend on the number of cores available.

Comment: How would you do this if you didn't have control of MyClass source code, but just wanted to inject it using bindings and other code in the Module config (Preferably without using Multibindings since that's not compatible with Gin yet)?

Comment: Snekse, you could create an @Provides method that takes the Provider<InjectedObject> as a parameter and calls the MyClass constructor at the end.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this suits your needs, but [Multibindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings) worked for me when I needed to inject multiple elements of the same kind (it produces a set though).

Comment: Multibindings produce Sets which are ordered (iteration over the elements is the same as the order elements are bound to the Multibinder). This means the Sets produced by Multibinding are often as good as a List or an array.

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to inject a `Provider<InjectedObject>` into your class, as Jesse mentioned:

```
public class MyClass {
  private final List<InjectedObject> injectedObjects;

  @Inject
  public MyClass(Provider<InjectedObject> injectedObjectProvider) {
    List<InjectedObject> objects = new ArrayList<InjectedObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      objects.add(injectedObjectProvider.get());
    }
    injectedObjects = Collections.unmodifiableList(objects);
  }
}
```

Doing this can be problematic. If `InjectedObject` is scoped as `@Singleton` or `@RequestScoped`, then each time you call `injectedObjectProvider.get()` you would get the same reference. Another problem with injecting a `Provider` to do this is it wouldn't be clear from the API that `MyClass` depends on multiple instances of InjectedObject. Finally, you've hardcoded in `MyClass` that it needs to be injected with five instances.

It's rare that you will need to inject a `Provider` into an object. Usually when I do this, it's because the scope of the current object means that it will be longer-lived than the scope of the dependent object (for instance, a `@Singleton` that needs access to a `@RequestScoped` object).

Instead of injecting a `Provider`, you can inject a `List<InjectedObject>` into the constructor, and create a provider method in a Guice module:

```
@Provides
MyClass prividesMyClass(Provider<InjectedObject> injectedObjectProvider) {
  List<InjectedObject> objects = new ArrayList<InjectedObject>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   objects.add(injectedObjectProvider.get());
  }
  return new MyClass(objects);
}
```

(you could, of course, bind using a `TypeLiteral`)

Why is this better? Even though you are still hard-coding five objects in this code, it isn't hard-coded in `MyClass`, so clients of `MyClass` (including the tests for `MyClass` itself) can choose to construct the object in different ways.

If hard-coding this knowledge in a Guice module isn't a good idea, you can instead create an interface that has a more specific contract than `Provider`

```
public interface InjectedObjectRepository {
  List<InjectedObject> getInjectedObjects();
}
```

Even if you decide that you want `MyClass` to be responsible for knowing how many instances to create, you might want to create an interface (perhaps named `InjectedObjectSupplier` so you could document explicitly that you expect a unique instance every time.

Comment: I like this answer, but how would you do this if you wanted each of the 5 `InjectedObject`s to be different impls managed by Guice?

Example:
`bind(InjectedObject.class).annotatedWith(AnnotA.class).to(ImplA.class).in(Singleton.class);`
`bind(InjectedObject.class).annotatedWith(AnnotB.class).to(ImplB.class).in(Singleton.class);`

Comment: @Snekse You can do what you want with a provider method (a method annotated with `@Provides`)

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you mean having 5 provider methods? `provideImplA()`, `provideImplB()`, etc... ????

Comment: `@Provides MyClass prividesMyClass(@AnnotA Provider<InjectedObject> a, @AnnotB Provider<InjectedObject> b)`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer so that people know how to inject an array since this come up first on a google search. I believe either of these will work:

In a Module's configure:
`bind(InjectedObject[].class).toInstance(someArray);`
or as a Provider method:

```
@Provides
InjectedObject[] getInjectedObject(@Inject Provider<InjectedObject> provider) {
  InjectedObject[] objects = new InjectedObject[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i] = provider.get();
  }
}
```